# Database not working with LAMP on Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, ubuntu

So I have a Ubuntu 16 computer on which I installed LAMP with this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

PHP works fine. If I try to log in to my database in my terminal using "mysql -u 'root' -p" and entering my password it works alright. I even could create some user accounts and the databases i need.

Tho, when I try to go on my website on "localhost/html/blablabla", if I have no interaction with the database the website shows up as it should. But if I include my database file the page goes totally blank.

- Yes, I'm sure the database exists and has all the tables it needs.
- Yes, I'm sure I didn't misstype the user ('root') and password in my database file.
- The website works fine on Windows using WAMP, it only bugs on linux.

Anyone has a clue what the problem is ?

Thanks !

Comment: Check your errors logs. Do some debugging. Currently not enough information.

Comment: Check if your php.ini `display_errors` directive is set as off, and you are getting the blank page instead of the mysql connection displayed error.

Comment: can you look into apache error log, without knowing error no one can help

Comment: I have no idea how to do all that. I'll check this out.